# Getting an Error like this - "jobParameters cannot be found on object of type BeanExpressionContext"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

We're creating a spring batch app that reads data from a database and writes in another database. In this process, we need to dynamically set the parameter to the SQL as we have parameters that demands data accordingly.

For this, We created a JdbcCursorItemReader Reader with @StepScope as I've found in other articles and tutorials. But was not successful. The chunk reader in our Job actually uses Peekable reader which internally uses the JdbcCursorItemReader object to perform the actual read operation.

When the job is triggered, we get the error - "jobParameters cannot be found on object of type BeanExpressionContext"

Please let me know what is that I am doing wrongly in the bean configuration below.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public JdbcCursorItemReader<DTO> jdbcDataReader(@Value() String param) throws Exception {

JdbcCursorItemReader<DTO> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<DTO>();

return databaseReader;
}

// This class extends PeekableReader, and sets JdbcReader (jdbcDataReader) as delegate
@Bean
public DataPeekReader getPeekReader() {
DataPeekReader peekReader = new DataPeekReader();
return peekReader;
}

// This is the reader that uses Peekable Item Reader (getPeekReader) and also specifies chunk completion policy.
@Bean
public DataReader getDataReader() {
DataReader dataReader = new DataReader();
return dataReader;
}


// This is the step builder.
@Bean
public Step readDataStep() throws Exception {
return stepBuilderFactory.get("readDataStep")
.<DTO, DTO>chunk(getDataReader())
.reader(getDataReader())
.writer(getWriter())
.build();
}

@Bean
public Job readReconDataJob() throws Exception {
return jobBuilderFactory.get("readDataJob")
.incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
.flow(readDataStep())
.end()
.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know what is that I am doing wrongly in the bean configuration below.

Your `jdbcDataReader(@Value() String param)` is incorrect. You need to specify a Spel expression in the `@Value` to specify which parameter to inject. Here is an example of how to pass a job parameter to a `JdbcCursorItemReader`:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcCursorItemReader<DTO> jdbcCursorItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['table']}") String table) {
    return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<DTO>()
            .sql("select * from " + table)
            // set other properties
            .build();
}
```

You can find more details in the [late binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding) section of the reference documentation.